# Biomes and landscaping this odd-shaped planet (part 2)

Tags: environment, climate, geography, map-making, axial-tilt

I'm still working on world map of [this pear-shaped planet](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/146555/drawing-landmasses-for-this-odd-shaped-planet) for my alien race, so I think land-to-water ratio would be something 40/60% or 30/70% (I don't know which one makes creatures much bigger), and some axial tilt that smaller side of planet doesn't get shadowed by larger side of this planet, which this planet spins vertically.

[image: re-cap of this pear-shaped megaplanet]

*Here's that planet on previous question for recap*

So I was thinking would this planet have one giant Pangaea or some several continents with some tons of archipelagos, if they live modern or futuristic civilization when they can have spaceships and travel on some other planets and space stations. Plus some that *"belt of mountains"* could have some gap that they can pass trough with boat...

And I want this planet have multiple biomes and not too catastrophic climates. Like farming rich biomes and forests with giant trees and animals (I mean megafauna and megaflora), and some deserts and snowy mountains too.

Comment: First off, this planet has an unstable spin if the long axis is the axis around which  the planet spins. Depending upon fluids on the planet, etc... the spin axis will quickly (years-centuries) orient itself to be perpendicular to the long axis. Secondly the planet is geologically unstable, or has negligible gravity. The dwarf planets in our solar system are large enough to have gravitically become orbs, but are still (largely) too light weight to hold water. But hey, you can make this world whatever you want.

Comment: @Kain0_0 So I need figure out just a mapping for my alien planet. I watched Artifexian videos about building planets and I'm still unsure does Pangaea or some clusters of giant archipelagos suits on this planet.

Comment: Even if such a planet exist, we can't expect a normal land/water distribution on it. Gravitational gradient would dictate that planet's "waist" would be a really low ditch where all the water will get collected, while its top and bottom would effectively become humongous mountains with no breathable air or clouds at the top.

Comment: Neither makes sense from the perspective of phsics is my point. The planet is either a sphere in which case yep continents, atmosphere, water, gravity, and all of that good stuff. Your planet from the perspective of physics is in one of two states. The first is a transitory state caused by the collision of two large bodies, in which case the planet is a Hades class planet of scorched lava and a toxic atmosphere. In the second state the bodies only weakly collided, ergo little to no gravity. That implies no atmosphere, and therefor no liquid water. Without water continents are not a thing.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fundamental incongruence here: this planet defies our current understanding of physics, thus by allowing it to exist you are throwing physics out of the window. Now, by asking if something like tectonics is plausible, you are trying to allow physics back from the back door.

Since you are allowing it to exist, you can make it have any configuration you like, as long as it doesn't break the suspension of disbelief in your audience. I.e. take as a reference Pandora in Avatar: is it physically possible that a planet is gravitationally bound yet it has some chunks which can float free in the air? Well, physically not, but plausible enough for the in-story world.

Same holds for your planet: give it the landmass distribution that you need, with the biomes that you want, as long as they seems plausible enough. I.e. the mountain ring can be a place where a lot of rain falls, due to the orography interacting with the winds, and therefore the other side of the mountain range might plausibly host a desert land.

Personally I would opt for a large archipelago scattered in the sea, resulting from the ejecta of the forming impact landing back on the planet.